# Can not remove the the border around grid after rendering

Tags: wpf, xaml

Here is my XAML and I see a border around the grid and I am not sure how to remove it.

```
 <Border
        BorderBrush="#971c1c"
        BorderThickness="5"
        CornerRadius="5">
        <Grid Background="#971c1c">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image
                Width="20"
                Height="20"
                Margin="3"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Source="/DataSuite.Administration.Console.WinClient;component/Resources/Integration_Error.png" />
            <ItemsControl
                Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="0,5"
                BorderThickness="0"
                FontSize="14"
                Foreground="White">
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="This is sample text for the error. Width will be set as per the value of message" />
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="This is sample text for the error." />
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="This is sample text for the error." />
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ItemsControl>
            <Button
                Grid.Column="2"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Background="Transparent"
                BorderThickness="0"
                Foreground="White">
                Dissmiss
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Control.Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                                <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

I have removed the border from the Itemscontrol and also this xaml is part of usercontrol and I have set the Borderthickness of usercontrol to 0 as well

Here is output that I am seeing.

[Rendered Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ELPX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to set the margin on the grid to -1.

```
 <Grid Background="#971c1c" Margin="-1">
```

Comment: hmm.. fellow wpf developer from Nagarro.. :) Nice to see your comment. I was in nagarro for 5 years never knew you.

Comment: Hehe.. it’s been 6 years for me now.. never knew you too!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set background of the border instead of the grid.

```
<Border
    Background="#971c1c"
    BorderThickness="0"
    CornerRadius="5">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Border>
```